# How do I access documentation Proposed Changes queue?

Tags: support, documentation

I just attempted to make a [change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/73557) to documentation, and the site indicates that review is required.

However, I cannot appear to find the page that allows me to contribute to the effort of reviewing other people's documentation changes.

Where is this UI?

---

I looked at the [Help Center Page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-proposed-changes) which mentions a Proposed Changes queue, but does not indicate where to find the said queue, and it does not come up under my review tab.

Comment: "Dashboard" tab for the tag > "Proposed changes" tab http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vim?tab=proposedchanges